# Not able to find an object by slug using frindly_id Couldn't find Article without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord, friendly-id

I'm Like you see I'm simply trying to have comments on each article show page also I'm using Friendly_id. The issue is that I'm not able to find the article by using its slug from the Comments controller and I'm not sure where the issue is.

## Comments controller

```
 class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @article = Article.friendly.find(params[:slug])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comments_params)
    redirect_to @article_path(@article)
  end

private

  def comments_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :body)
  end
end
```

## Article Controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]



def index
    @Articles = Article.all
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
      if @article.save
        redirect_to @article
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

    def show
      find_article
    end

    def edit
      find_article
    end

    def update
      @article = Article.find_by_slug(params[:id])
      if @article.update(article_params)
        redirect_to @article
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
      @article.destroy
      redirect_to root_path
    end

    private

    def find_article
      @article = Article.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :content, :slug)
    end
  end
```

## comment form

```
<%= form_for ([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :Name %>
  <%= f.text_field :Name %>
<br>
  <%= f.label :Body %>
  <%= f.text_area :Body %>
<br>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

## comment

```
<p><%= comment.content %><p/>
```

## Article Model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

## Comment Model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

## Routes

`Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  root 'articles#index'

  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
end`

Comment: Can you post the code for the `Article` and `Comment` model?

Comment: @mqngo They are there now :)

Comment: Can you share your routes.rb?

Comment: I see nothing outright wrong with the code. Have you use the `rails console` to validate that the `Comment` is properly attached to the `Article`? I see that you have the `params[:slug]` from `create` function `CommentController` but didn't accept it in the `permit` clause. Did you get it from `routes`?

Comment: This is the Rails console output 

2.3.1 :004 > article = Article.find(1)
  Article Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<Article id: 1, title: "title", content: "cool stuff", created_at: "2016-06-28 17:08:03", updated_at: "2016-06-28 17:08:03", slug: "title">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it should be like this:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @article = Article.friendly.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comments_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

private

  def comments_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :body)
  end
end
```

Comment: I think it did something! still having an error thought but a different one. undefined method `content' for #<Comment:0xb3495bc>
Did you mean?  concern 
and its pointing to <%= comment.content %>

Comment: could you post an example comment? `Comment.first`

Comment: 2.3.1 :001 > Comment.last
  Comment Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments"  ORDER BY "comments"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Comment id: 1, Name: nil, Body: nil, article_id: 1, created_at: "2016-06-29 00:11:59", updated_at: "2016-06-29 00:11:59"> 
2.3.1 :002 >

Comment: as you can see, your comment has a body, name column, but no content. changing to `body` should solve your issue. BTW, I'd be careful with moving away from Rails conventions as DB column should start with a small letter e.g `body` not `Body`